# Whats the wrong with passing me as parameter in CallbyName funktion under vb6?

Tags: vb6, callbyname

I want to pass the sourceform, from which I use the CallByName-function. Somehow, it doesn't work in way I post it down there.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
  'CallByName Form1, "TestFkt", VbMethod, Nothing, Command1   '<--- works
  CallByName Form1, "TestFkt", VbMethod, Me, Command1         '<--- Problem
End Sub

Public Function TestFkt(ParamArray myParams())
  Dim oForm As Object
  Set oForm = myParams(0)

  ' ...
End Function
```

The error reported from vb6 is runtime error 450: "Falsche Anzahl an Argumenten oder ungültige Zuweisung zu einer Eigenschaft". I think the first reason is not the problem, because the commented line above works. It seems more, that the problem has something to do with the keyword me.

Anybody some idea?

Comment: google translate == "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not `CallByName`:

```
TestFkt Form1, Me
```

Is also not valid as you cannot pass `Me` when using a `ParamArray`. This is a peculiarity of `Me` which is something of a special case.

Workaround:

```
Dim fMe As VB.Form: Set fMe = Me
CallByName Form1, "TestFkt", VbMethod, fMe, Command1
```